# How to make file upload through a form not required?

Tags: php, if-statement, file-upload

I’m working on my first PHP file upload code and have a few questions. Sorry, I’m a newbie but look forward to learning and could use some help.

I need to know how to make a File Upload through a form as a **not required** step.

Right now I have the code doing an `if/else` but if the user doesn’t upload a file then I still get an error. Probably because the `if` statement comes back as `false`.

Do I need another `else` statement or is there something else like an `or` statement?

```
    // Where the file is going to be placed 
    $target_path = "uploads/";

    /* Add the original filename to our target path.  
    Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)){
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
    }
    else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
```

Comment: What does move_uploaded_file() look like?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap everything in

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploadedfile'])) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code should be

```
if (isset($_FILES['uploadedfile'])) {
    // Where the file is going to be placed 
    $target_path = "uploads/";

    /* Add the original filename to our target path.  
    Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
}else{
    echo "No File uploaded";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap all your code in an if statement to see whether or not the file has been uploaded. Otherwise you will get warnings and notices stating the variables are undefined. Something like this

```
if(!empty($_FILES['uploadedfile'])) {
    // Where the file is going to be placed 
    $target_path = "uploads/";

    /* Add the original filename to our target path.  
    Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
        " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
} else {
    //nothing needed in here or echo some message
}
//Your other required stuff should be here
```

Warning: i havent tested this

Comment: apologies for the edit but i didnt see the part where you mentioned the else